# Loop Change Page Title JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

So I have this code

```js
function changeTitle() {
  var title = document.title;
  var variable = document.querySelector('.liconspan').innerHTML;
  console.log(variable)
  setTimeout(changeTitle, 3000);
  document.title = title;
}
changeTitle();
```

I want to loop changing the title like the following:

"One" > "Two" > "One" > "Two" etc.. just sample texts will be replaced with the text I want and the actual title to loop and change from.

Cheers!

Comment: What is it that you expect that code to do, why do you expect it to do it, and what happens instead?

Comment: I want the page to notify the user that he's got an alert, exactly like Facebook, let's say that my page title is "Test Page", there will be a timer that will change "Test Page" to "You got a notification" until the user sees that notifcation

Comment: So toggle it, you have no logic in there to toggle...

Comment: I'm fairly new to JS, what do you mean?

Comment: What is it in your code that you expect will change the title? The only thing you ever set `document.title` to is the value it already has.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var first = true;
function setTitle()
{
    if(first)
        document.title = "One";
    else
        document.title = "Two";
    first = !first;
}
setInterval(setTitle, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  // Title loop

  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var titles = ['Welcome To FanBoost!', 'Apply Now!'];
    var currentIndex = 0;
    var intervalDuration = 10000; // 10 seconds
  
    function changeTitle() {
      document.title = titles[currentIndex];
      currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % titles.length;
    }
  
    changeTitle(); // Initial title
  
    setInterval(changeTitle, intervalDuration);
  });
```

this should help